# InteropBitmap Code examples

Tags: c#, interopbitmapimage

Has anyone worked on InteropBitmap? I didn't find any code examples. If you have any links to tutorials or any code examples, please post here.

Comment: Perhaps the example in this thread will help?  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/69a21a24-1971-4fe2-8e76-05158a255c84/